# How to find all equal attributes from another relation using Relational Algebra

Tags: database, relational-database, relation, relational-algebra

I have a relation `A`:

```
Store       Product
----------  ----------
store A     P1
store A     P4
store B     P1
store B     P2
store B     P3
store B     P4
store C     P2
store C     P3
store C     P4
```

and another relation `B`:

```
Product
----------
P1
P2
P3
```

How to find all stores (`store B` only in this case) that sell every product from relation `B` using Relational Algebra query?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the relational division operator.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.